# How to use array of strings as in query in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a very big array of about 100 entries whose each element is like 'ab12ef' like that.
Name of the array is **a_ids** like this.

```
a_ids=["ab12ef", "cd23gh"]
```

I need to use that array in my mysql query. I have used it like the following:

```
SELECT SUM((IF(id in (#{a_ids.join(',')}),1,0)) a_count from tab group by id;
```

But the problem is that final query that is generated is like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(id in (ab12ef, cd23gh),1,0)) a_count from tab group by id;
```

And it is not working because I think it should have been like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(id in ('ab12ef', 'cd23gh'),1,0)) a_count from tab group by id;
```

I have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following mapping:

```
a_ids.map {|v| "'#{v}'" }.join(',')
```